# Tikz overlay element creates unwanted margins

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, vertical-alignment, margins

I have a Tikz element that is the header banner for my document, which is overlayed such that it is aligned to the top of the page.

I also have a section of text, that is re-aligned under the tikz header using a tmargin from geometry.

However this section of text is not aligned according to the margin, as the leftover tikz element creates an entity that adds an invisible margin to the document, ruining the alignment.

This can be clearly seen by using `fbox` on the `tikzpicture`

If I use `\noindent` before this, I can move the box to the left.

**How can I remove this "Box" or its margins such that my section can become re-aligned with the page margins?**

Small working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\titlefont{\LARGE\bfseries}
\newcommand\subtitlefont{\Large\bfseries}
\newcommand{\header}[2]%
 {\fbox
   {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
    \node[outer sep=0, inner sep=0, rectangle, fill=green!30,
          anchor=north, minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=2.5cm]
      (box) at (current page.north){};
    \node (picture) at (box)
      {\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a.png}%
      };
    \node [outer xsep=3mm, inner xsep=0, right, align=left]
      (name) at (box.west){\titlefont #1 \\ \subtitlefont #2};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
   }%
 }
\begin{document}
\header{Title}{Subtitle}
\section{Section}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! We can only help you if you provide a *working* example, not just code snippets. I have completed the code such that everyone with a full TeXlive installation can run it; I think it still shows the effect. Feel free to adjust it if you think I have missed something important.

Comment: Check the [fancyhdr package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr). It is made for achieving such effects.

Comment: What am I missing about the margins? I don't see anything wrong.

Comment: Tikz overlay should take up no space at all.  \fbox{} is indented.  Section isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the eso-pic package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\titlefont{\LARGE\bfseries}
\newcommand\subtitlefont{\Large\bfseries}
\newcommand{\header}[2]%
 {\fbox
   {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
    \node[outer sep=0, inner sep=0, rectangle, fill=green!30,
          anchor=north, minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=2.5cm]
      (box) at (current page.north){};
    \node (picture) at (box)
      {\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a.png}%
      };
    \node [outer xsep=3mm, inner xsep=0, right, align=left]
      (name) at (box.west){\titlefont #1 \\ \subtitlefont #2};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
   }%
 }
\begin{document}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\AtPageUpperLeft{\header{Title}{Subtitle}}}
\section{Section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for that Ulrike, it works :) 
Could you explain why though?

And is it not possible to fix this without the need of another package?

Comment: If you don't want your tikzpicture to disturb the spacing you should put it somewhere where it doesn't do harm. The header is a sensible place, and eso-pic is offering a nice interface to use if for such things. You can write similar code manually but as you are willing to use the large tikz package I don't see why you won't want to use the much smaller eso-pic too. Also I doubt that your own code would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using the `fancyhdr` package. `\raisebox` and `\makebox` shrink the height, depth and width of the `tikzpicture` to zero. `\raisebox` additionally shifts the header to the right position. `\chead` of the `fancyhdr` package is used to set the middle header to the `\header` command on the first page, and to nothing on the others.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\titlefont{\LARGE\bfseries}
\newcommand\subtitlefont{\Large\bfseries}
\newcommand{\header}[2]%
 {\raisebox{6ex}[0ex][0ex]{\makebox[0em]{\begin{tikzpicture}%
    \node[outer sep=0, inner sep=0, rectangle, fill=green!30,
          anchor=north, minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=2.5cm]
      (box) at (current page.north){};
    \node (picture) at (box)
      {\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a.png}%
      };
    \node [outer xsep=3mm, inner xsep=0, right, align=left]
      (name) at (box.west){\titlefont #1 \\ \subtitlefont #2};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
 }}}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\lhead{}
\rhead{}
\chead{\ifthenelse{\value{page}=1}{\header{Title}{Subtitle}}{}}
\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\end{document}
```