# Including an image on a page (possibly with tikz)

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, positioning

I am trying to include an image in my document, and I don't know if I am doing it the right way.

What I want is that on a certain page, I place an image in the background (only being in the background on a small part of the page) AND have it not affect the placement of anything else (so removing the image or reintroducing the background image doesn't change the position of the text in the page).

I have so far been using the tikzpicture environment, though I am not convinced this is the best way to do this.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay] 
\node[xshift=10.5cm, yshift=-3.3cm, opacity=0.3, inner sep=0pt] at (current
page.north west) {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{myimage.png}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

After this code, I have included the text for the page normally.  So the page begins with a title like

```
\begin{center}
     \textbf{\Large Some kind of title}
\end{center}
```

etc etc.

This seems to do what I want, but it slightly shifts the text in the page down.  I thought the overlay command was supposed to prevent this.

Comment: Have a look at the wallpaper package. Also, a full minimal working example helps. At least include a picture with what you have and what you want.

Comment: @Huang_d Remember, one needs 10 reputation to be able to post a picture. If you upvote them, they'll be able to comply ! Ok I'll do it for you.

Comment: @Hammar check this out : [How to use background image in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167719/how-to-use-background-image-in-latex) and [Insert a full page image](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136900/insert-a-full-page-image)

Comment: Maybe look into the `eso-pic` package?

Comment: \begin{center} adds vertical space (as opposed to \centering).  While a tikzpicture overlay takes up no space horizontally, it does count as a \null, so adding a blank line after it will start a new paragraph.

Comment: A tikz overlay has no size, but it is nevertheless a box and so can affect spacing. Put it in a place where a zero-box doesn't do harm. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/330884/2388.

Comment: @John  I think you were right.  I removed the space in between the tikz environment and the center environment to no affect, but using \centering seems to have done the trick.  Thanks!