# TikZ overlay picture influences text around it

Tags: tikz-pgf, overlays

I would like to place an overlay picture on a page without disturbing the rest of the page's content. However, when I put the source code for the overlay picture above or below a section command, either the section header or the following text are shifted downward.

Can this be circumvented? Or is there maybe another, entirely different way for placing additional text above/below the regular page content?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay] 
\draw [line width=1mm,opacity=.25] (current page.center) circle (3cm); \end{tikzpicture}

\section{Section}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay] 
\node [rotate=60,scale=10,text opacity=0.2] 
    at (current page.center) {Example};
\end{tikzpicture}

Both, the section header and this text, are shifted because of the overlay TikZ pictures.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Put the picture in the header, e.g. with the eso-pic package. Or inside a paragraph, e.g. behind "Both". See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/330884/2388

Comment: Another related post that showed up now: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22873/tikzpicture-with-overlay-takes-up-space. Sorry for the duplicate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A viable solution is to use the `background` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, showframe}
\usepackage[pages=some]{background} 

\begin{document}

\backgroundsetup{opacity=1, scale=1, angle=0, contents={%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \draw [line width=1mm,opacity=.25] (current page.center) circle (3cm);
    \node [rotate=60,scale=10,text opacity=0.2] 
        at (current page.center) {Example};
    \end{tikzpicture}}}
\BgThispage

\section{Section}

Neither the section header nor this text are shifted because of the overlay TikZ pictures.

\clearpage
No background on this page.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Even though a `tikzpicture` with overlay has zero size, it's still there, as far as TeX is concerned. So you have "something" on a line, then `\section`, which starts a new paragraph. After the `\section` you again have something, then a paragraph break, then the text. If you place both `tikzpicture`s immediately before the text after `\section`, without any spaces or empty lines, you'll get what you're after. Or just as well, use just one `tikzpicture`.

The frame is from the `showframe` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,showframe}

\begin{document}


\section{Section}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay] 
\draw [line width=1mm,opacity=.25] (current page.center) circle (3cm);
\node [rotate=60,scale=10,text opacity=0.2] at (current page.center) {Example};
\end{tikzpicture}% <- end of line comment to remove space from newline
No spaces or paragraph breaks around the tikpicture, so no apparently empty lines, and thus no shifting.

\end{document}
```